# Specification of mid-2010 15" MacBook Pro LCD panel?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've been enjoying my mid-2010 15" MacBook Pro for almost two years now, and am quite satisfied.

However, I never knew what the computer's display's exact specifications are (other than it is LED backlit and has resolution of 1680x1050).

Does anyone have such information? I.e. static contrast ratio, response time, panel technology, etc. etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly Apple has long since stopped releasing such specific information itself.  You can try to find this out by searching for replacement LCDs on ebay.  They'll sometimes give the partnumber from the LCD manufacturer, which you can then search for to find out the panel specifications.

Comment: There are 2 resolutions for 15" MBPs - the 1440x900 and the 1680x1050 resolution screens. Which version do you have?

Comment: @JW01 I have the 1680x1050, any ideas?

Comment: Found a bit more information. According to another article I found, the 1680x1050 display uses a TN panel. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using information from the [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2010-Display-Assembly/IF161-053) Team, I managed to get the part number of the display.

```
Apple Part #:      661-5483
Product code:      IF161-053-1 glossy, standard resolution
                   IF161-053-3 glossy, high resolution
                   IF161-053-5 anti-glare, high resolution
```

You can use this information for further research. I was not able get more than this:

```
Size:           15.4"
Resolution:     1440 x 900 WXGA+
Backlight:      LED
Surface:        Glossy
Aspect Ratio:   16:10 wide
Screen Type:    Thin-film transistor (TFT), Active-matrix Liquid Crystal Display (LCD)
```

[source [1](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2010-Display-Assembly/IF161-053),[2](http://www.lcds4less.com/Apple-laptop-lcd-screens/661-5483.shtml)]

Comment: +1, good find! Original poster still needs to let us know which screen he has - this one or the 1680x1050 version.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP582):

> **Display**
>   15.4-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit glossy widescreen display with support for millions of colors
>
> **Supported resolutions**: 1440 by 900 (native), 1280 by 800, 1152 by 720, 1024 by 640, and 800 by 500 pixels at 16:10 aspect ratio; 1024 by
>   768, 800 by 600, and 640 by 480 pixels at 4:3 aspect ratio; 1024 by
>   768, 800 by 600, and 640 by 480 pixels at 4:3 aspect ratio stretched;
>   720 by 480 pixels at 3:2 aspect ratio; 720 by 480 pixels at 3:2 aspect
>   ratio stretched
>
> Optional 15.4-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit widescreen display with 1680
>   by 1050 pixels (glossy or antiglare)

Unfortunately, as @Adam has noted, Apple doesn't publish more than that on its official site.

UPDATE: According to an [OS X daily article](http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/16/new-macbook-pro-15-hi-res-screen-comparison/), the 1680x1050 display uses a TN panel.